# Can't execute a specific program via PHP to digitally sign a file

Tags: php, batch-file, exec, digital-signature, shell-exec

I'm using IIS 6.0 and PHP and I'm trying to write a php script that automates a process to 1) create an installer and 2) digitally sign the installer. I've created a batch file that does each individually. If I go to the server and manually run the batch files, both work perfectly. If I run them via PHP, only the installer is created but it is never digitally signed. I have confirmed that:

1. All files referenced in the batch files have full rights for the IUSR_[COMPUTER-NAME] user.
2. It is not an issue with the file not being fully created yet by the first batch file. I can put the already created Setup.exe file in the folder and run only the second batch file via PHP with the same results.
3. The batch file is actually getting run. I've put a MKDIR command in the same batch file after the digital signing command and the folder is created.

The code I use via PHP to run the batch files is:

```
system('cmd /c C:\\Inetpub\\createInstallers\\step1.bat');
```

The create installer batch file looks like this:

```
"C:\Program Files\Inno Setup 5\ISCC.exe" C:\Inetpub\createInstallers\createInstaller.iss
```

I'm using Inno Setup to do this found here: http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php

The digital signing batch file looks like this:

```
"C:\Inetpub\createInstallers\DigiCertUtil.exe" sign /noInput "C:\Inetpub\createInstallers\Setup.exe"
```

This is done with DigiCertUtil.exe's command line feature explained here:

https://www.digicert.com/util/utility-code-signing-command-line.htm

As far as I can tell, absolutely nothing happens. I don't believe there are any error messages (but I am a little fuzzy on how to check for them). NULL is returned if I run the digital sign command via shell_exec like this:

```
    $result = shell_exec('"C:\\Inetpub\\createInstaller\\DigiCertUtil.exe" sign /noInput "C:\\Inetpub\\createInstaller\\Setup.exe"');
    var_dump($result);
```

Does anyone have any idea why this might not be working? Could this be some permissions issue or security limitation?

Comment: If your language requires backslash as an escape then you are missing one in this line `system('cmd /c C:\Inetpub\\createInstallers\\step1.bat');`. Most languages require (because Windows requires - but some languages/objects fix it for you) that paths with spaces be enclosed in quotes. So first thing is to run your command from the command prompt until you get a command line that works. Second is check permissions on the folder (why are you doing it in inetpub). When I last installed IIS 15 years ago I thought that was the name of it's root directory???

Comment: @phd443322 Thanks for the typos catch with the backslashes. In my code the escaping was correct, but I had typed it out wrong here. Inetpub is not the web root in our system. Instead, we have multiple root folders for different web applications within Inetpub. Permissions on the files look correct. I still have no idea why this isn't working.

Comment: So first thing is to run your command from the command prompt until you get a command line that works

Comment: @phd443322 I have been able to do that. Unfortunately, it does not work for some reason when PHP executes that line. It works fine if I manually open cmd.exe and run it, but not if I have PHP run the command.

Comment: But I want to see a working command. Then security details (eg `icacls c:\inetpub` and what accounts does PHP run under and what account does a typed command run under. Is UAC on or off. Change your command to cmd /k and see if you get any messages. Most languages return either exceptions or return values. According to PHP's doc a second optional parameter will hold the return value. Also PHP has a safe mode that may prevent your bat from running according to it's docs. http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.system.php

Answer (score 0):

I found the underlining problem and the answer. The problem was that the certificates are imported in the user's personal store on a per user basis, so when I tried to run the DigiCertUtil program via PHP, it could not find the certificates because the IUSR did not have a personal store with the certificate to use. IUSR is a temporary user and thus does not have a personal store. There might be a way to put the certificate into the machine's store, but I could not find it.

Instead, I used PSExec to run the program locally but with a different user than the IUSR account, like this:

```
shell_exec('C:\\Inetpub\\createInstallers\\psexec \\\\127.0.0.1 -accepteula -u myUser -p myPassword -i cmd.exe /c C:\\Inetpub\\createInstallers\\DigiCertUtil.exe sign /noInput C:\\Inetpub\\createInstallers\\Setup.exe');
```

No batch files required! It would be just as easy to run a batch file as a different user though with this same methodology.